# Python code to filter styles from 1000+ pages

Tags: python, regex

i have converted the word file in to html file, but there is a problem, the MS-word automatically adds some style to the pages.

for example

```
<div align="center"></div>
<p style=""></p>
<table cellpadding="0">

<tr><img src="...."></img></tr>

</table>
```

i want to output to be as

```
 <div></div>
<p></p>
<table>

<tr><img src="...."></img></tr>

</table>
```

i dont want the img inline styles to be removed.

thanks in advance

```
update:  if it is very hard to keep img style in the file. please give me the code excluding that part. it is very urgent for me and i cant edit 1000 pages manually
```

Comment: A regex for this is **wrong**. Use a HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup (as long as it can also *write* HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove styles for a known list of tags, I don't think its necessary to use a full weight HTML parser. Something like

```
expr = r'((?<=<div)|(?<=<p))[ ]+.*?>'
html_text = re.sub(expr,'>',html_text)
```

works just fine. Of course, you would use an array of tags you want to replace to generate the (?<=

If you have a list of style tags that you want to remove, it's even easier. Just generate an expression like

```
expr = r' (style|align|myStyleTag)=".*?"'
```

with re.sub.

If you need a dynamic combination thereof, use a parser.

Edited in response to comments by OP:

Unfortunately, lookbehind needs fixed-size expressions, so <.* or similar won't work. If you don't have a fixed tag list, it's probably better to use a preexisting framework.

An ugly way around this would be something like:

```
expr = "("
for i in range(1,8): ## or whatever the max/min tag lengths are
    expr += "(?<=<[a-zA-Z]{" + str(i) + "})|"
expr = expr[:-1] + ")[ ]+.*?>"
```

But that's pretty bad style.

Comment: expr = r'((?<=<[.*]))[ /s ]+.*?>' will this work. actually p, div, and table are just examples.  there are many elements inside with inline styles. 
thanks for your help and valuable time...

Comment: well yeah, that would probably work (except use [^\s]* in the first part I think, because you only want the tag itself to be matched i.e. "<div"), but you said you wanted to leave image src tags. In that case maybe add an explicit ?!src= after the check for the "open tag"? The problem there is that it won't catch things like <img style="" (any number of styles here) src="" (any number of styles here)>, but let me think of a better solution. I'll get back to this

Comment: hey there, i am just a starter and i dont know to run the program even. so better help me give the full statements. it is very kind of you. an update, i have to load the html from a .html file.

Comment: expr = r'((?<=<[.*]))[^\s]*+.*?>'  do you mean like this?

Comment: >>> import re
>>> expr = r'((?<=<div)|(?<=<p))[ ]+.*?>'
>>> html_text = re.sub(expr,'>',""" <div sometext adjkfhad></div> """)
>>> print html_text
 <div></div>

your code worked, but how to make it work for all html tags

Comment: the code you said bad style gives this error'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    html_text = re.sub(expr,'>',""" <div id=sometext></div> <p idsdhf></p>  """)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unbalanced parenthesis'

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me, see http://ideone.com/VF8Sy. Maybe check your indents?

Comment: he there, thanks i got the code running. as i am having only one point i cant vote. anyways thanks a lot you have saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [elementtree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). parse the file remove all style attributes you don't need and write the file.

With elementtree this should be a 5 liner.